# Material UI ExpansionPanel header background color

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to change the color of the header on the MUI ExpansionPanel.I can get the header to any color I want when it's not expanded, but then when it's expanded the whole control (summary and header) change to the same color. Obviously these styles don't work, but this is where I'm at right now:

```
 ExpansionPanelStyles = {
        root: {
            width: '100%',
            backgroundColor: 'red',
        },
        header: {
            backgroundColor: 'yellow',
        },
        expanded: {
            '&$expanded': {
                backgroundColor: 'blue',
            },
        },
    };
```

Using the style I posted the whole thing is the same color when expanded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically target the 'ExpansionPanelSummary' for your header styles, and then use the expanded class to change the background color of the header when the panel is expanded:

```
const ExpansionPanelStyles = {
root: {
    width: '100%',
    backgroundColor: 'red',
},
header: {
    backgroundColor: 'yellow',
    '&$expanded': {
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
    },
},
expanded: {},
};

// Usage in the component:
// <ExpansionPanel classes={{ root: classes.root, expanded: classes.expanded }}>
//     <ExpansionPanelSummary classes={{ root: classes.header, expanded: classes.expanded }}>
//         ...
//     </ExpansionPanelSummary>
//     <ExpansionPanelDetails>
//         ...
//     </ExpansionPanelDetails>
// </ExpansionPanel>
```